# Facebook Event API returns error

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api

### The Problem

I am accessing Facebook event functions from the given API, in order to create Facebook event for my application on my Facebook profile. However, the API returns error, while doing so. The error is not found every time. In other words, it is not working for any particular data, any time in a day. Thus, unable to solve the issue.

Please provide us more info on - why the error (basically, it returns an Object reference error) is return?

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Login with your facebook account (facebook-connect)
2. Call Facebook Event URL - `https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/events` and pass all required parameters like User Id, Access Token, Event Name, Start Date, End Date, Event Desc and Privacy Type. (facebook-graph-api)
3. Returns error with request.GetResponse()

**Expected Behavior**
Successful Facebook Event to be created & returns the valid Facebook Event Id

**Actual Behavior**
Returns the error (any time of the day)